# Best practice to update value from another class

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to flutter, so please excuse my experience.

I have 2 classes, both stateful widgets.
One class contains the tiles for a listview.
Each tile class has a checkbox with a state bool for alternating true or false.

The other class (main) contains the body for creating the listview.

What I'd like to do is retrieve the value for the checkbox in the main class, and then update a counter for how many checkbboxes from the listview tiles have been checked, once a checkbox value is updated. I am wondering what the best practices are for doing this.

Tile class

```
class ListTile extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ListTileState createState() => _ListTileState();
}

class _ListTileState extends State<ListTile> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool selected = false;
    return Container(
      child: Row(
        children: [Checkbox(value: selected, onChanged: (v) {
          // Do something here
        })],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Main Class

```
class OtherClass extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _OtherClassState createState() => _OtherClassState();
}

class _OtherClassState extends State<OtherClass> {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Text("Checkbox selected count <count here>"),
          ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    // Do something to get the selected checkbox count from the listview
            return ListTile();
          }),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: that is explanatory, but yet not enough. please provide some code to let me give you the best solution for you situation

Comment: It's brief, but I hope you get the idea

Answer (score 3):

Hope this is you are waiting for

```
   class OtherClass  extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _OtherClassState createState() => _OtherClassState();
}

class _OtherClassState extends State<OtherClass> {
  bool selected = false;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  var items = [
    Animal("1", "Buffalo", false),
    Animal("2", "Cow", false),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("title")),
        body: Container(
          child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: items.length,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemBuilder: (ctx, i) {
                return Row(
                  children: [
                    Text(items[i].name),
                    ListTile(
                      id: items[i].id,
                      index: i,
                    )
                  ],
                );
              }),
        ));
  }
}
```

ListTileClass

```
    class ListTile  extends StatefulWidget {
  final String? id;
  final int? index;
  final bool? isSelected;

  const ListTile ({Key? key, this.id, this.index, this.isSelected})
      : super(key: key);
  @override
  _ListTileState createState() => _ListTileState();
}

class _ListTileState extends State<ListTile> {
  bool? selected = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        width: 20,
        child: Checkbox(
            value: selected,
            onChanged: (bool? value) {
              setState(() {
                selected = value;
              });
            }));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend using a design pattern such as BLoC or using the Provider package. I personally use the [Provider Package](https://pub.dev/packages/provider). There are plenty of tutorials on youtube which can help get you started.